# Problemas com acentuação no Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Como posso, por exemplo, fazer uma busca por nós que contém um atributo com o valor de *'jose'* e retornar os nós que possuem esse atributo com o valor de *'jose', 'josé',* ou *'josê'* ? Ou seja, fazer com que as buscas ignorem acentuação e ou cedilhas, assim como em outros bancos de dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Expressões Regulares

Já brinquei há algum tempo atrás com o Neo4j e lembro que os nomes usados sempre eram tratados como `case-sensitive`. Não lembro de ter visto funcionalidades de *collations* igual aos bancos SQL.

De qualquer forma, segundo essa [documentação do Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.3/cypher/clauses/where/#query-where-regex), você pode usar expressões regulares nas suas *queries*. No seu caso você precisaria especificar as possibilidades de acentos que deseja conforme o *input* do usuário.

Por exemplo:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.name =~ 'jos[eéê]'
RETURN n.name, n.age
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. Deu certinho. Eu tinha lido sobre as expressões regulares, porém estava escrevendo errado. Quanto ao case sensitive, eu utilizo a função toLower mesmo tanto na entrada quanto na string de comparação do banco em tempo de busca.